# Hadoop hardware disk choice

Tags: hadoop, hardware

We're evaluating the options of setting up a large hadoop cluster. Now we actually have the choice to choose from these 3 setups:

- 300x server with 12x 1TB disk
- 150x server with 12x 2TB disk
- 100x server with 12x 3TB disk

The other server specifications are identical. What would be your choice, and more important, why?

Best regards,
Robin

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the 3TB (or 4TB disks) over the 1TB but I'm worried about what RAID level you're planning on using - PLEASE say it's R10 or R6 with that many consumer disks and not R5.

Comment: What metrics are YOU using to make your decision?

Comment: @Chopper3: who says they're consumer disks? (OK, they probably are). Also, with Hadoop you throw individual disks at it and let Hadoop handle the replication. No RAID.

Comment: In hadoop we use NO RAID, just as @MikeyB suggests.

Comment: @MikeyB are there any 3TB disks with 100% duty cycle available yet? I thought the first 2TB ones that are at least supported to that level only just came out 3-6 months ago? Happy to be wrong.

Comment: @Chopper3: Here's one: http://www.hgst.com/internal-drives/enterprise/ultrastar/ultrastar-7k3000

Answer (score 1):

The more servers you have, the more horsepower you have. They all have identical capacity, however only someone with knowledge of what will be done with this cluster can decide between the options.

edit: I'm including disk IO horsepower in this. The more disks you have, the larger the number of random IO/s you can push, as well as the higher MB/s you can push under a sequential workload. Each spindle (disk) adds a linear amount to the aggregate performance.

Comment: I understand that we have less CPU and less memory. But is there also a negative performance impact on the disk speed (e.g. read / write)?

Comment: Yes, you have less disk horsepower as well. I didn't differentiate, however the more heads you have, the more IO/s or MB/s you can push.